# Is a Pushdown Automaton with an Epsilon Transition a NDPA?

Tags: automata, pushdown-automaton

Let's suppose we have this PA:

`-> q0 (e, e -> $) --> q1`

Where:

`q0` is a final and initial state;
`e` is epsilon (empty); and q1 is another state.

If the automaton were to read the `e` word, it could either make the transition to q1 or stop in q0.

So, would this PA be Non-Deterministic?

My teacher says it wouldn't because, in reality, there's only one path for the automaton to follow: since the word is empty and all symbols had already been consumed in q0, it would make no transition whatsoever; however, we're not sure if he's right (by the way, he says that in order for a PA to recognize a word it needs not only to be in a final state but also all the word's symbols must have been consumed).

Answer (score 1):

For a PA to be deterministic it must follow at least the following rule:

If there is an epsilon transition from a state q, there must not be any alphabet transition from that state.

So in your case, if there isn't any other rule, the PA is deterministic.

Comment: Even in that case I specified? Note that the q0 state is not only the initial state, but also a final one.